# Django cache works in development but not production

Tags: python, django, caching, nginx, gunicorn

I have a django project which utilizes the django cache (the default local-memory cache) to store the remainder of a large queryset for retrieval later. This system worked as I intended in development (using the built-in django webserver) but in production (nginx and gunicorn) the cache seems to simply not function at all.

I can't find anything stating there was something specific necessary to get the cache working in a production environment. All suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

```
default_cache = get_cache('default')
default_cache.clear()
default_cache.set(request.user.id, object_list, CACHE_AGE)
```

Answer (score 2):

The local memory cache is not really suitable for production. It's exactly what it says: local to the current process. That means that in a multi-process environment, which your production setup will almost certainly be, something cached in one process won't be visible in another one. Note that the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) mention this specifically.

Install redis or memcached and use them as cache backends instead.

Comment: I've installed memcached and python-memcached, using the default port configuraton (I've tried 127.0.0.1:11211 and 0.0.0.0:11211) but the result is the same. It doesn't seem as if the cache is working at all.

Comment: Then you're going to need to show more of your code. What exactly is object_list? Where exactly are you doing that set call? Where are you getting the data back?